# htaccess rewrite of directory to variable fails on localhost

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

Let's take something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6688106/627517). So, I'm looking to rewrite:

`http://www.example.com/test` to

`http://www.example.com/page.php?v=test`

with:

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?v=$1 [L]`

This takes me to the page `http://www.example.com/test/?v=test`

Why does it not stay on `http://www.example.com/test` without the trailing slash and the query string.

PS: I'm using WampServer on Windows

Answer (score 0):

in `RewriteRule` don't put `/` and the begining!

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for that comment, but that didn't fix the issue. Removing the slash didn't change the result.

Comment: that **is** the whole `.htaccess` plus a `RewriteEngine On` before hand. I should also note that I'm using WampServer

Answer (score 0):

The problem arises if `test` is an existing directory on the server. Apache then uses the [DirectorySlash Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) to "fix up" the URL pointing to the directory by adding a trailing slash.

I'm answering my own question here, but the solution (as the above link states) is to add `DirectorySlash Off` to .htaccess